# Passing NSMutableArray to UIView class becoming nil

Tags: ios, arrays, class, nsmutablearray

I am trying to pass an NSMutable array from a View Controller class to a UIView class.

Code:

```
UIView.h class

-(void)init:(NSMutableArray *)ary;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *valenceArray;

UIView.m 

-(void)init:(NSMutableArray *)ary
{
     self.valenceArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:ary];
    NSLog(@"%@",_valenceArray);
 }

-(void) drawgraph

{
   for (int i = 0; i < _valenceArray.count; i++)
    {
        NSString *string = [_valenceArray objectAtIndex:i];
        double value = [string doubleValue];
        NSLog(@"%f", value);
    }
}
```

The init method prints out the contents of the array passed through. But when i call the draw graph method the array resets to nil.

Code for setting the array:

```
Grid *grid = [[Grid alloc] init];
[grid init:_array];
```

Any Idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I suggest you to change name of method `-(void)init:(NSMutableArray *)ary` which has same name with the standard init method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need to initialize an array if you are passing them from another UIView or controller. Its because you are reinitializing the array. Just remove the init method & directly pass array to the draw method without any initilization.

```
-(void) drawgraph:(NSMutableArray *)ary
{
    NSLog(@"%@",ary);
}
```

& call it

```
[grid drawgraph:_array];
```

Comment: This is a fix of course, but this doesn't explain/fixes the part where he might want to hold on to the array for later use.
So at the very least in the draw graph function add " self.valenceArray = ary; "

Comment: @ŃikeKamstra: It can be used anywhere in that class.

Answer (score 2):

Replace `init` method with below code:

```
-(void)init:(NSMutableArray *)ary
{
     _valenceArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:ary];
    NSLog(@"%@",_valenceArray);
}
```

Also access it using `self.valenceArray` in graph method. Also assign `self.valenceArray` from parameter array value:

```
-(void) drawgraph:(NSMutableArray *)ary {

   self.valenceArray = ary; 

   for (int i = 0; i < _valenceArray.count; i++)
    {
        NSString *string = [self.valenceArray objectAtIndex:i];
        double value = [string doubleValue];
        NSLog(@"%f", value);
    }
}
```

> An instance variable is a variable that exists and holds its value for the life of the object. The memory used for instance variables is allocated when the object is first created (through alloc), and freed when the object is deallocated.
>
> Unless you specify otherwise, the synthesized instance variable has the same name as the property, but with an underscore prefix. For a property called firstName, for example, the synthesized instance variable will be called _firstName.
>
> Although it’s best practice for an object to access its own properties using accessor methods or dot syntax, it’s possible to access the instance variable directly from any of the instance methods in a class implementation.

[Encapsulating Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html)

Answer (score 0):

If the view Grid is an outlet of viewController. You should use the outlet property to call the init function. Maybe as @KudoCC said you need to change the method name.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will fix it, but your method:

```
-(void)init:(NSMutableArray *)ary {}
```

should return itself (UIView) else the reference is still null. Also since your init could possibly(shouldn't though) overwrite the usual init, it may mess up things so change this to something like:

.h :

```
-(id)initWithArray:(NSMutableArray *)ary;
```

.m :

```
-(id)initWithArray:(NSMutableArray *)ary
{
    self = [super init];
    self.valenceArray = ary;
    NSLog(@"%@",_valenceArray);
    return self;
}
```

Otherwise, check if the array which is send through, actually is filled.

Also I didn't notice the Grid class, that should be changed to:

```
Grid *grid = [[Grid alloc] initWithArray:_array];
```

Comment: Didn't work. The array is filled because the NSLog within the init manages to print out the array contents. But when i call the drawgraph method within this class. The array is reset to nil.

Comment: hmm could you share the output of the array (the NSLog) when it gets called on the init?

Comment: 2014-12-08 12:20:26.416 AffectVisualiser[1929:3847613] (
    1,
    1,
    "-1",
    1,
    "-1",
    1,
    "-1"
)